# Import Automation for Mobile Studio [Solved]

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, mobileconnect, sms, ftp

I'm creating an automation to import people from a CSV list into a MobileConnect Contact List. I've created the Import Definition. After i dragged "Import Mobile Contacts" to "Step 1", i got empty SMS folder. I don't understand. Does this mean the import definition is not under SMS folder? Or raw files are not on sftp?

[image]

Comment: If you only have import def for DE, the Import Mobile Contact SMS folder would be empty. you need to create a import def for List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to import data from a CSV via an automation. You need to create an import activity inside Contact Builder. Then you decide to push the data SMS all contact or a specific list.

In Automation Studio, you should have access to this import via Import Activity or via Import Mobile Contacts.